# How can i change the element's CSS from loop result?

Tags: reactjs

I recently developed by using React, but i found that can't change the element's CSS (the value of certain fields or class name) from a loop result. For example:

```
const {data} = this.props;

map(data, (result, index) => 
  <div key={index} className="result-main animated bounceIn">
    <div className="result-content">{result.name}</div>
    <span 
      className="result-remove"
      onClick={() => this.handleRemove(result.id)}
    >X</span>
  </div>
)
```

now, i want to remove an element via `handleRemove(param)` and change its class name like: `bounceIn` change into `bounceOut`, to produce an animation effects. Is there any way to help me to solve this?(When i click `<span>`, parent `<div>`'s class name will be changed)

Expecting your answer!

Answer (score 0):

refer link http://plnkr.co/edit/wFUtCfOYqTYfUFTn1sBk?p=preview

```
  var HideMe=React.createClass({
  Hide:function(event)
  {
    var Selected=$(event.target)[0].id;
     $("#"+Selected).removeClass('show');
    $("#"+Selected).addClass('hide');
  },
  Show:function(event)
  {
    var Selected=$(event.target)[0].id;
     $("#"+Selected).removeClass('hide');
    $("#"+Selected).addClass('show');
  },
  render:function()
  {
    return(
      <div>
      <div>
       <span id="1" onClick={this.Hide}>Click me to Hide</span>
        <input type="button" id="1" value="Show" onClick={this.Show}/>
      </div>
     <div>
      <span id="2" onClick={this.Hide}>Click me to Hide</span>
        <input type="button" id="2" value="Show" onClick={this.Show} />
     </div>
      </div>

      )
  }
});
React.render(
  <HideMe />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```